# How to run the same method concurrently without waiting for loop to end?

Tags: python, function, loops, methods, concurrency

As seen in my code below, I have a function that produces an animation of a circle when the user clicks on the window. My problem is, for me to have another circle appear and move after one is already spawned, I have to wait for the previous one to finish its loop of movement. After one circle has finished its "i in range" loop at the end of the snowfall function, then I can click and produce another circle. I want to be able to click at any time and have as many circles moving simultaneously as I want (I'm aware I've limited it to 10 times in the code under the function). It looks like I need away to run the same method multiple times concurrently.

```
from graphics import*
from random import*


win = GraphWin("Graphics Practice", 500, 500)

colours = ["blue", "red", "orange", "purple", "green", "black", "brown", "yellow", "pink"]

def snowfall(randColour):
    point = win.getMouse()
    circle = Circle(point, 40)
    circle.draw(win)
    circle.setFill(colours[randColour])
    for i in range(1000):
        circle.move(0, 1)
        time.sleep(0.002)

randColour = randint(0, 8)
for i in range (10):
    repeatColour = randColour
    snowfall(randColour)
    randColour = randint(0, 8)
    while randColour == repeatColour:
        randColour = randint(0, 8)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

One of my failed attempts at multithreading this:

```
from graphics import*
from random import*


win = GraphWin("Graphics Practice", 500, 500)

colours = ["blue", "red", "orange", "purple", "green", "black", "brown", "yellow", "pink"]

def snowfall(randColour):
    point = win.getMouse()
    circle = Circle(point, 40)
    circle.draw(win)
    circle.setFill(colours[randColour])
    for i in range(1000):
        circle.move(0, 1)
        time.sleep(0.002)

randColour = randint(0, 8)
t1 = threading.Thread(target = snowfall, args = randColour)
for i in range (10):
    repeatColour = randColour
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    randColour = randint(0, 8)
    while randColour == repeatColour:
        randColour = randint(0, 8)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Most recent code:

```
from graphics import*
from random import*


win = GraphWin("Graphics Practice", 500, 500)

colours = ["blue", "red", "orange", "purple", "green", "black", "brown", "yellow", "pink"]

class Snowflake(object):
    def __init__(self, randColour):
        self.circle = Circle(point, 40)
        self.circle.draw(win)
        self.circle.setFill(colours[randColour])

    def next_frame(self):
        self.circle.move(0, 1)

randColour = randint(0, 8)
sprites = []    
for i in range (100):
    repeatColour = randColour
    point = win.getMouse()
    sprites.append(Snowflake(randColour))
    randColour = randint(0, 8)
    while randColour == repeatColour:
        randColour = randint(0, 8)
    for s in sprites:
        while True:
            s.next_frame()
            time.sleep(0.02)
    win.getMouse()
    randColour = randint(0, 8)
    sprites.append(Snowflake(randColour, point))

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Comment: Try using Multi threading in the programming  hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are attempting to `join` thread `t1` immediately after starting it. To `join` a thread is to wait for it to finish, so instead of starting ten threads, you are starting and then waiting for a thread ten times.

**However, threading is the wrong approach here.**  Most graphics packages do not allow multiple threads to draw to the same graphics context, for good reasons of performance and fluidity.  This means that you need to turn your drawing threads "inside out", putting the state of each animated object in a "sprite", so that the state of each animated object is in its own instance.  Then, instead of using separate threads for each sprite, you run through all your sprites and update them in a single loop, as shown below.

(Note that I introduced `win.checkMouse()`, which does a non-blocking check for a mouse event, and therefore allows you to add a sprite per click, which is what I believe you intended.)

```
from graphics import *
from random import *

win = GraphWin("Graphics Practice", 500, 500)

colours = ["blue", "red", "orange", "purple", "green", "black", "brown", "yellow", "pink"]

class Snowflake(object):
    def __init__(self, randColour, point):
        self.circle = Circle(point, 40)
        self.circle.draw(win)
        self.circle.setFill(colours[randColour])

    def next_frame(self):
        self.circle.move(0, 1)

randColour = randint(0, 8)
sprites = []
for i in range(100):
    point = win.checkMouse()
    if point:
        randColour = randint(0, 8)
        sprites.append(Snowflake(randColour, point))
    for s in sprites:
        s.next_frame()
    time.sleep(0.1)
win.close()
```

Comment: I understand your concept of using multiple objects (each one being a sprite), but when trying to implement your code, the circles now no longer animate (move). They appear when I click, but are stuck in place.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a complete top-to-bottom solution, so you can see exactly how the sprite loop relates to the main loop, and also demonstrated how to use `win.getMouse()`. (I also had a mistake where I used `this` in place of `self`, which I fixed.)

Comment: Please see my most recent code (updated). I had to add a while loop otherwise the circle(s) wouldn't continuously animate. Now I'm back where I started but with different code, one circle moving at a time. I think this is because the while loop keeps going and the program never reaches the next checkMouse, but the while loop is needed for continuous movement, causing the animation. How can I have more circles spawn and animate from the code I've left above? Thank you.

Comment: There are several problems in your recent code. Having the `while True:` within the sprite loop means that it will never stop animating the first sprite in the list. Next, the `time.sleep` call should not be inside the sprite loop; that should only be done once per frame, after *all* sprites update. Finally, new `Snowflake` instances are being created every single time (two per loop), rather than in response to a new mouse event. Take a close look at the structure of the code in my answer. Try running it, and adding print statements or modifying it to understand it.

Comment: Got it working partially as expected, thank you. I also managed to make it so the same colour can't repeat consecutively, as I had it do before in my version of the code. One problem with your code is that in the range part, the program ends when that range is reached for the first sprite. Say the first circle moves 400 times (for i in range 400), once it makes its 400th move, the whole program ends. Other circles do appear and move when clicking, but all stop when the first circle reaches 400.

Comment: Also, what is the "s" in "for s in sprites"? I get sprites is the list, but what's s? How is s something in the list?

Comment: I see now that the number in range is acting as a timer, not as how many movements the circle will make.

Comment: Yes, that loop `for i in range(100):` simply ensures that the program ends after 100 frames. If you want it to run indefinitely, you need to add some extra code to make sure that sprites that are no longer in play are removed from the list. If you don't, `sprites` will continue growing and your performance will get dragged down.

Comment: The `s` in `for s in sprites:` is a loop variable. `for` assigns each element of `sprites` to `s` in turn. This means that within the loop, `s` is the "current sprite".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180882/discussion-between-4u53r-and-derek-t-jones).